# Spring Data Redis Streams, Cannot figure out what is happening to my unacknowleded messages?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I am using the following code to consume a Redis stream using a Spring Data Redis consumer group, but even though I have commented out the acknowledge command, my messages are not re-read after a server restart.

I would expect that if I didn't acknowledge the message, it should be re-read when the server gets killed and restarted.  What am I missing here?

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public StreamMessageListenerContainer eventStreamPersistenceListenerContainerTwo(RedisConnectionFactory streamRedisConnectionFactory, RedisTemplate streamRedisTemplate) {

        StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> containerOptions = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions
                        .builder().pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(100)).build();

        StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> container = StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(streamRedisConnectionFactory,
                        containerOptions);

        container.receive(Consumer.from("my-group", "my-consumer"),
                        StreamOffset.create("event-stream", ReadOffset.latest()),
                        message -> {
                                System.out.println("MessageId: " + message.getId());
                                System.out.println("Stream: " + message.getStream());
                                System.out.println("Body: " + message.getValue());
                                //streamRedisTemplate.opsForStream().acknowledge("my-group", message);
                        });

        container.start();

        return container;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the Redis documentation on how streams work, I came up with the following to automatically process any unacknowledged but previously delivered messages for the consumer:

```
// Check for any previously unacknowledged messages that were delivered to this consumer.
log.info("STREAM - Checking for previously unacknowledged messages for " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " event stream listener.");
String offset = "0";
while ((offset = processUnacknowledgedMessage(offset)) != null) {
        log.info("STREAM - Finished processing one unacknowledged message for " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " event stream listener: " + offset);
}
log.info("STREAM - Finished checking for previously unacknowledged messages for " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " event stream listener.");
```

And the method that processes the messages:

```
/**
 * Processes, and acknowledges the next previously delivered message, beginning
 * at the given message id offset.
 *
 * @param offset The last read message id offset.
 * @return The message that was just processed, or null if there are no more messages.
 */
public String processUnacknowledgedMessage(String offset) {
        List<MapRecord> messages = streamRedisTemplate.opsForStream().read(Consumer.from(groupName(), consumerName()),
                        StreamReadOptions.empty().noack().count(1),
                        StreamOffset.create(streamKey(), ReadOffset.from(offset)));
        String lastMessageId = null;
        for (MapRecord message : messages) {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(String.format("STREAM - Processing event(%s) from stream(%s) during startup: %s", message.getId(), message.getStream(), message.getValue()));
                processRecord(message);
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(String.format("STREAM - Finished processing event(%s) from stream(%s) during startup.", message.getId(), message.getStream()));
                streamRedisTemplate.opsForStream().acknowledge(groupName(), message);
                lastMessageId = message.getId().getValue();
        }
        return lastMessageId;
}
```

Comment: Say there is a poison message which always produce an error in consumer side. The above approach will process the poison message endlessly. Ideally, we should use the XPending api which has deliveryCount based on the deliveryCount say if it exceeds 5 then we should move it to deadletter stream or we can XClaim it. but i dont find the spring-data-redis stream api's for Xpending and Xclaim.

Comment: The version 2.3.1.RELASE of spring-data-redis already has a pending function. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/StreamOperations.html#pending-K-org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.Consumer-